# Descriptive programming in Selenium (Java)

Tags: java, selenium

Здравствуйте,
раньше использовал descriptive programming в QTP для лписания объектов вместо создания репозитория обектов. Подскажите, есть ли что-то подобное в Selenium WebDriver (Java)? Я знаю есть основные методы определения обектов по Xpath, ID, tag и т.д., но как только эти элементы меняются программистом например поменяли ID, то Selenium не может обнаружить обект на странице и тест останавливается. Хотелось бы сделать так чтобы при измениее элемента программистом, Selenium мог это определить и успешно найти элемент на странице. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Селениуму все равно нужно на что-то завязываться для идентификации элемента, это же не ИИ. Если идентификаторы меняются, то ищите то, что не меняется. Классы, атрибуты, текст элемента, названия и атрибуты соседних тегов. Если абсолютно все может поменяться, то остается только кликать по точным координатам)) Но это гораздо хрупче конструкция будет.

Вообще, договаривайтесь с программистами о том, как будете искать элементы, чтобы они эти характеристики не меняли.